# OpenCart products links on home page are not pointing to correct url

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I've started setting up opencart for my online store, everything was working correctly till yesterday, but now its showing some incorrect behavior. On main page I have some "featured" products , When a user click on it, it should navigate user to that product's page for details and url is something like following

```
http://mystore.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=57&product_id=49
```

but the url which is its navigating to is something like

```
http://mystore.com/iphone
```

hence its not navigating user to product's page and stays on same page (i.e. index page).
Also, I'm unable to login to my admin panel.

I guess I've done something wrong but can't track it. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Store url is [this](http://www.thefriendsmall.com)

Thanks

Comment: The url to your site is not opening. Can you check it?

Comment: Updated, Please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something very not alright with *.htaccess* file in the root folder of your site. Try to rename it back to *.htaccess.txt* .

OR

Rename *.htaccess.txt* to *.htaccess*. Looks like you have you turned **on** SEO setting in admin but it requires *.htaccess* file.

Although check if you have right url addresses in both **config.php** files, root and admin.

Comment: You are right, I've turned on SEO setting from admin panel but I guess it wasn't able to access .htaccess file. I've turned off that setting from admin and its working okay. Thanks